# typescript heroku syntaxerror: cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, heroku

i am using react native with typescript
i upload my server node js to heroku
and i get this error "heroku syntaxerror: cannot use import statement outside a module"
the problem is that i using typescript and i cant use require

and i try to change things like ts-node / target : es6
on tsconfig
and its gave me another errors

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}

package json :
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the TypeScript code directly. Instead, you need to compile it to JavaScript and run that.

Add a `build` script to your `package.json`, and update your `start` script to refer to `server.js` instead of `server.ts`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc",
  "start": "node server.js"
}
```

You can test this out locally by running `yarn build` (or `npm run build`), then `yarn start` (or `npm run start`). Once you have confirmed that it works, commit the change and redeploy.

(You may also want to [specify an output directory for your JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outDir), and you'll probably want to update your `.gitignore` to ignore the compiled JavaScript files.)